# O que é abstração?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software, abstração

*Web* afora e também aqui no Stack, às vezes se fala em "abstração" quando o assunto é arquitetura/engenharia de *software* e orientação à objetos, principalmente.

- O que é a tal "abstração"?
- Por que ela é importante?
- Como consegui-la na prática?

Comment: +1 uma pergunta muito interessante, dará com certeza excelentes respostas.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Abstração em informática](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o_%28programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) tem seu sentido derivado do [mesmo conceito em filosofia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o), que é "isolar um elemento à exclusão de outros". Seu uso é muito parecido com aquele feito em matemática - em vez de resolver um problema para um domínio bem específico (ex.: tinha quatro laranjas e comi duas, quantas tenho?) transformar esse problema em um problema mais geral (ex.: `x = 4 - 2`) e resolver *esse* problema, aplicando a resolução de volta ao problema original.

Dando um exemplo concreto, como se implementa um somatório?

```
var resultado = 0;
for ( var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ )
    resultado += array[i];
```

E como se implementa um produtório?

```
var resultado = 1;
for ( var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ )
    resultado *= array[i];
```

Nota-se que potencialmente existem N problemas do mesmo formato: começa-se com um valor inicial, aplica-se uma operação envolvendo esse valor e um elemento da entrada, o resultado do mesmo combinado com o próximo elemento, etc, até se atingir o resultado final. Ao abstrair o problema dessa forma (i.e. isolar as características comuns, parametrizando pelas específicas) pode-se chegar a uma [solução mais geral](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
function reduce(array, fn, valorInicial) {
    var resultado = valorInicial;
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ )
        resultado = fn(resultado, array[i]);
    return resultado;
}

var somatorio = reduce([1,2,3,4,5], function(a,b) { return a + b; }, 0);
var produtorio = reduce([1,2,3,4,5], function(a,b) { return a * b; }, 1);
```

Outro exemplo mais comum no dia-a-dia é o uso de tipos e subtipos, e a criação de funções "genéricas" que atuam sobre vários tipos. Em vez de se implementar uma solução específica para um tipo de dados, implementa-se uma que atende a diversos tipos distintos, assim evitando a duplicidade do código.

Por que isso é importante, deve ser evidente. Como conseguir na prática, aí já é uma questão de raciocínio matemático: tentar enxergar similaridades dentre os diversos conceitos com o qual lidamos, descrever essa similaridade na forma de um novo conceito (mais geral, ou mais abstrato) e - conforme os recursos oferecidos pela sua plataforma de escolha - desenvolver soluções voltadas a esse novo conceito, de modo a ser facilmente reaproveitável pelos conceitos mais específicos.

Naturalmente, muito desse trabalho já foi feitos por outros, de modo que quanto mais conhecimento você tiver - quanto mais contato com trabalho de terceiros envolvendo abstração - mais facilidade você terá para identificar na prática quando uma abstração se aplica ao seu caso, de modo a desenvolver/reutilizar soluções nesse sentido. (Faça o que eu digo, não faça o que eu faço: estude matemática!)

#### Camadas de Abstração

Por fim, não diretamente parte da pergunta mas bastante relacionado, há o conceito de "camadas de abstração": muitas vezes para se resolver um problema "em alto nível" é desejável se poder ignorar os detalhes "de baixo nível". Por exemplo, ao escrever "crie uma janela" (ex.: `new JFrame()`) você ignora todo o trabalho que o computador tem para desenhar as formas geométricas que compõem essa janela, o tratamento da entrada (teclado, mouse) sobre essa janela, etc. Você está raciocinando em alto nível, e ter de pensar nesses detalhes todos só iria te atrapalhar.

Por outro lado, quem cria uma biblioteca para implementar uma interface gráfica, o faz de forma bem genérica, sem se preocupar exatamente com para que ela será usada (não *como* será usada, isso é parte da API, mas sim as janelas específicas que serão criadas). Ao mesmo tempo que nessa fase ignora-se como o computador vai desenhar os pixels na tela, como a memória principal vai interagir com a placa de vídeo, etc. Isso é trabalho de quem cria bibliotecas gráficas (como o OpenGL e o DirectX).

Programadores que se concentram em soluções para o usuário final em geral estão no nível de abstração mais alto (i.e. usar as ferramentas disponíveis para atender a uma necessidade do mundo real), mas nem sempre possuem as ferramentas no melhor nível possível. Por isso, se você perceber que está (ou vai) se repetindo demais na construção de um sistema, considere que talvez seja interessante abstrair um pouco o problema com o qual está lidando - criando soluções para essa abstração, e em seguida aplicando-as ao problema real. Isso é usar abstração na prática.

Answer (score 4):

- O que é a tal "abstração"?
  Eu aprendi e tenho em minha mente a seguinte definição:

> Abstração para a OO, nada mais é do que você observar comportamentos e estruturas do dia-dia, e transformá-los em uma linguagem computacional.

- Por que ela é importante?

> Por que ao utilizá-la sabiamente ou seja do jeito certo, você conseguirá com menos esforço e mais qualidade criar sistemas computacionais que mais se aproximarão à expectativa do usuário. Ou seja você realmente conseguirá atenteder a necessidade do usuário.

- Como consegui-la na prática?

> Sem contar que esse é um processo árduo, e que poucas pessoas dominam ele com maestria, você conseguirá com muito estudo, e prática ao mesmo tempo. Tá certo não é tão árduo assim, mas se mais pessoas dominassem como deveria propriamente dito, muitos sistemas não se seriam emcontrados em estados deploráveis como vemos tão facilmente hoje em dia.

Essa é a minha opinião, baseada no que aprendi sobre a engenharia de software até agora!, tentei ser breve e espero ter ajudado!

Valeuu! :D

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

*O que é Abstração?*

> Abstração é o ato de resumir características ou ações similares partilhadas entre dois ou mais objetos.

*Por que ela é importante?*

> Porque quando bem feita reforça o paradigma de virtualizar o mundo real.

*Como consegui-la na prática?*

> Observando estados e comportamentos similares entre dois ou mais objetos.

---

De acordo com a Wikipedia:

> Em Ciências da Computação, **abstração** é o processo de separação de idéias específicas dos métodos de trabalho. Estruturas computacionais são definidas por seus significados (semântica) enquanto escondem detalhes de como elas funcionam. Abstração tenta fatorar detalhes de um padrão comum para que programadores possam trabalhar de forma mais próxima à realidade humana.

*"Mas é uma droga tão maçante!" - Tank, Matrix*

Orientação a Objetos não tem como um dos mais básicos objetivos representar o mundo real de forma programática? Um objeto **Porta** representa uma porta no mundo real, com suas características (proprieddes) e ações (métodos).

E assim como no mundo real várias coisas têm similaridades, sejam de características ou ações. A diferença é que não entre si, afinal se fosse assim abririamos a porta do carro e a da geladeira seria aberta junto.

Continuemos com o exemplo do objeto **Porta**. Vamos agora introduzir um objeto **Portão**. Ambos são basicamente a mesma coisa, tem características partilhadas, ações em comum, mas um **Portão** tem algumas coisas que uma **Porta** comum não tem (controle remoto, talvez).

Sem abstração teríamos:

```
class Porta {

    private $isOpen = FALSE;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function open() {

        $this -> isOpen = TRUE;
    }

    public function close() {

        $this -> isOpen = FALSE;
    }
}

class Portao {

    private $isOpen = FALSE;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function open() {

        $this -> isOpen = TRUE;
    }

    public function close() {

        $this -> isOpen = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Qualquer coisa que um Portão precisasse para abrir/fechar, por exemplo até poderia ser implementada em seus próprios métodos, mas de todo jeito não eliminaria o *code smell* da repetição.

E se repetiriamos isso de novo, de novo e de novo é hora de abstrair!

No nosso cenário didático podemos resumir tanto a **Porta** quanto o **Portão** a:

- Possuir uma estrutura física que bloqueia ou libera o acesso ao interior / exterior (a porta em si)
- Abrir e fechar

A primeira é uma característica e as duas últimas, ações. Nossa refatoração preliminar ficaria:

```
class Porta {

    protected $isOpen = FALSE;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function open() {

        $this -> isOpen = TRUE;
    }

    public function close() {

        $this -> isOpen = FALSE;
    }
}

class Portao extends Porta {}
```

Abstraimos a *flag* de estado da Porta, se aberta ou fechada e as ações de abertura e fechamento reduzindo os objetos.

> Ações públicas são melhor caracterizados por Interfaces aqui desconsideradas

Answer (score 3):

#### Uma definição e exemplos

Quando você tem um conjunto de conceitos e abstrai (destaca, puxa para fora) tudo o que é supérfluo deixando somente o essencial, e muitas vezes dando um nome ao resultado disso, está produzindo uma **abstração**. Você está omitindo desse conjunto de conceitos ou dessa informação composta por outras tudo o que é detalhe e preservando o que é essencial para entendê-la e representá-la.

Quando você vê um rosto com certa combinação de feições, seu cérebro abstrai isso para "seu irmão", "sua professora", etc. Seu irmão Zé alegre, triste, com o braço engessado, é sempre seu irmão Zé. Nosso cérebro se desenvolveu para interpretar e trabalhar com similaridades. Por exemplo, "sair para caçar" pode variar no detalhe mas o objetivo é sempre o mesmo.

A interface simples para dirigir um veículo (volante, marchas) é uma abstração do seu funcionamento completo e complexo (motor, virabrequim, engrenagens, rebimboca da parafuseta) que não precisa ser exposto na sua completude para o motorista.

Mais ainda, isso permite dirigir diferentes implementações de veículos de forma parecida, porque preservou-se o essencial e minimizou-se as diferenças. "Abstraiu-se" o mecanismo de condução.

*"Ir ao mercado"* é mais abstrato que *"virar à direita, andar cem metros, parar no semáforo, etc."*

#### Utilidade

Abstração é usada para esconder complexidade. Você a esconde e passa a trabalhar num *nível maior de abstração*, isto é, saindo do mais concreto e indo para o mais abstrato, e muitas vezes mais simples e automático, como no exemplo de ir ao mercado, ou mandar um robô pegar um objeto, ou salvar um objeto de software em banco de dados, ou fazer uma operação bancária em um caixa eletrônico, etc.

Pode inclusive realizar substituições nas suas funcionalidades subjacentes (como trocar um motor de um carro ou uma implementação de algoritmo de busca) sem afetar o funcionamento básico de nível mais alto. É a segunda utilidade da abstração: encapsular (isto é, isolar ocultando) um mecanismo de funcionamento que se torna assim substituível.

Outra vantagem da abstração (e da modularização) é na divisão de tarefas. Cada pessoa ou equipe pode se concentrar em trabalhar em uma parte específica de um sistema, que é responsável por determinadas tarefas, sem se preocupar com as especificidades das outras partes. Isso facilita tanto a compreensão como a evolução de cada parte e do sistema como um todo. Isso acontece por exemplo no design de computadores ou de softwares com certa complexidade.

#### Em programação

Dividir código em funções é um mecanismo primário de abstração. **Funções** são abstrações.

Em orientação a objetos, um tipo ou subtipo (como por exemplo, no Java, uma **classe** ou uma **interface**) podem ser considerados abstrações. São modelos, muitas vezes de algo do mundo real, e modelos são abstrações, simplificações, que escondem a complexidade de algo e fornecem uma maneira simples de acesso às suas capacidades.

Ao mesmo tempo, as linguagens orientadas a objetos frequentemente disponibilizam esse recurso a partir de recursos mais simples das mesmas, como variáveis, funções e tipos simples de dados, que são "blocos de construção" (perdão, tijolos) para produzir esses tipos mais abstratos de dados.

#### Em sistemas computacionais (hardware + sistema operacional):

Um computador é inteiramente construído sobre abstrações.

Processador e memória RAM são feitos basicamente de portas lógicas (frequentemente *NOT-AND* ou *NAND*), que vêm sendo há muitas décadas construídas com transistores (que atuam como chaves liga-desliga e/ou reguladores de corrente/tensão) e que podem ser combinadas formando outras portas lógicas (por exemplo, uma porta *NAND* recebendo duas entradas iguais vira uma porta *NOT*, que por sua vez é, como se pode ver, um pouco mais abstrata; uma porta *NAND* ligada a uma porta *NOT* vira uma porta *AND*; e assim por diante).

Com portas constrói-se circuitos lógicos diversos, como somadores, decodificadores, *latches* ou travas, que vão sendo usados para construir módulos ainda mais complexos, como registradores e unidade lógica-aritmética. E assim vai, até o processador e a memória, bases da arquitetura von Neumann (lê-se von Nóiman), que assim como outras é capaz de executar um sistema operacional, também composto por módulos e camadas, que por sua vez executa programas e acessa redes de computadores (que também são implementadas por meio de camadas).

#### Separação de responsabilidades

Acho que a única coisa que não foi falada até o momento é que essas camadas todas, se bem definidas, permitem a *separação de responsabilidades* (*separation of concerns*).

Cada camada é responsável por suas próprias atividades, fazendo uso de camadas inferiores como prestadoras de serviços e por sua vez fornecendo serviços para camadas superiores.

#### Trabalhando com abstrações

Sobre trabalhar com abstrações, a resposta aceita explica bem. Em programação isso envolve trabalhar com tipos abstratos ou então identificar similaridades e comportamentos comuns dentro de uma porção de código e abstraí-los, isto é, extraí-los para algo mais generalizado, como uma função ou classe, que irá resolver o problema mais geral e poderá ser aplicado de volta no problema original e em outros semelhantes.

Por exemplo, identificar que você está imprimindo boletos e comprovantes em dois lugares diferentes e generalizar isso para uma única função `imprimir(Documento doc)` ou mesmo para uma classe `Documento` com um método abstrato `Documento.imprimir()` implementado em suas subclasses. O exemplo do *reduce* da resposta aceita é mais prático e concreto ainda, embora requeira alguma noção de programação funcional.

Tenha cuidado com suas abstrações. Abstrações incorretas introduzem complexidade desnecessária e dificultam a manutenção do código, aumentando os custos e atrasando os prazos para o desenvolvimento, sem contar a perda de qualidade do *software*.

Também quando possível procure evitar que sejam [abstrações furadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/357).

---

#### *Disclaimer*

Esta foi a abstração sobre abstração que tentei transmitir a você a partir da minha abstração mental sobre abstrações, utilizando algumas abstrações, como por exemplo frases em português mostradas na tela desse mecanismo muito abstraído que é o computador. Se não conseguiu entender, abstrai aí. :)