# O que é abstração de um framework?

Tags: terminologia, framework, abstração

Em uma outra pergunta que fiz [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195009/organiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-pastas) no Stack Overflow sobre a organização de pastas em um determinado projeto, recebi um comentário dizendo:

> Estrutura de pastas acaba sendo uma pegada mais "pessoal", a questão é você respeitar os paradigmas, tais dos *design patterns*, que é outra jogada, outra questão. Eu particularmente recomendo uma estrutura como de repositórios e MVC.
>
> Por qual motivo não esta utilizando abstração de um *framework*?

Apesar de me interessar pelo [link](http://br.phptherightway.com/) proposto no comentário, e continuar pesquisando sobre o assunto e até achar uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23103/o-que-%C3%A9-abstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o) relacionada, ainda me ficou a dúvida de: **O que é abstração de um *framework*?**

Comment: Acho que ele queria te perguntar "por que você não está usando um framework". Ou seja, por que não usar as abstrações e padrões de projetos mais conhecidos e consolidados, e já implementados em algum framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Abstração é esconder a complexidade de um problema de forma generalizada. É criar uma camada que seja algo simples de entender e usar para fazer tarefas mais complexas.

A abstração falada é só um jeito bonito de dizer para usar um *framework*, para usar algo que já está pronto e indica a forma de usar e não precisar ficar pensando nisso.

Claro que o *framework* é feito para te entregar pronto algumas coisas complexas, então ele acaba agindo como uma abstração.

Tem várias formas de lidar com a complexidade. *Framework* não é a única e muitas vezes não é a melhor.

Um dos problemas é que se a pessoa não souber o que está fazendo o *framework* não ajuda muito e passa a ilusão que a pessoa está fazendo certo.

Eu não gosto de usar uma abstração se eu não conhecer a concretude que ela esconde, ainda que eventualmente eu faça isso por força da necessidade momentânea.