# Até que ponto utilizar frameworks?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação, framework

De forma geral, até que ponto e quando devemos utilizar *frameworks*?

É importante previamente aprender a linguagem "bruta", ou pode-se iniciar o aprendizado através de *frameworks*?

Quais as desvantagens de utilizá-los de forma recorrente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Até que ponto utilizar *frameworks*?

Difícil responder isso, "até que ponto" é algo muito aberto, muito livre pra interpretação de cada um.

> De forma geral, até que ponto e quando devemos utilizar *frameworks*?

Usamos *frameworks* para aproveitar uma infraestrutura para um tipo de tarefa ou aplicação como um todo realizado por alguém que já teve os mesmos problemas que você terá e te entrega "pronto". Ele dá produtividade (até a página 3<sup>*</sup> :) ), evita certos erros, mas dá baixa flexibilidade também.

> É importante previamente aprender a linguagem "bruta", ou pode-se iniciar o aprendizado através de *frameworks*?

Isso tem muito de opinião. Eu acho que você só deveria usar um *framework* depois que sabe fazer sem ele. Deve aprender os fundamentos e saber como cada coisa funciona. Mas o que vejo hoje em dia é que quase todo mundo usa um *framework* porque não quer aprender como programar de verdade. Em geral é a única opção que a pessoa tem. Não a toa que hoje muitos softwares sofrem de baixa qualidade.

Mas eu admito que para alguns programadores o *framework* pode ser uma dádiva, sem ele o código da pessoa seria muito pior justamente por ela não dominar o que está fazendo.

Um bom aprendizado é criar um *framework*, mesmo que não seja para usá-lo. Se fizer certo, se souber evoluí-lo pode aprender muitos conceitos de desenvolvimento com isso. Na verdade, isso vale para quase tudo em programação, não só *frameworks*.

> Quais as desvantagens de utilizá-los de forma recorrente?

- Você tem que fazer o que o criador determinou que é bom, o que nem sempre é bom para você. Provavelmente terá situações que não dá para resolver bem com ele, e pode ser bem complicado resolver. Muitas vezes a solução ficará torta, ou acontece o que vejo muito é que a o programador diz que não pode fazer.

  Ele é inflexível. Mesmo quando tem alguma flexibilidade não sem um custo de complexidade que não existiria se fizesse na mão só o que precisa.

  É de conhecimento universal que eles são limitados e não resolvem tudo. E se resolver é porque você tinha algo tão simples que o uso deles não era tão necessário assim.

  O termo que usamos para isto é "opinativo" que em alguns casos pode até ser uma vantagem.
- Você fica preso a ele, se um dia precisar de uma solução muito diferente joga tudo fora. E/ou se prende ao seu modelo, aprende fazer tudo do jeito dele e não consegue fazer diferente, começa achar que todos os problemas são pregos porque você só tem o martelo na mão, pode até acertar o uso a primeira vez, mas na próxima ele não serve mas você usará assim mesmo.

  Se você só aprender o *framework* nunca poderá se chamar desenvolvedor, nunca terá os melhores empregos, é só um *personalizador* de *framework*, a maioria das vagas disto são subempregos. A diferença de salário de um para o outro chega ser de 10 vezes.
- Porque a pessoa acha que não precisa aprender nada em detalhe é comum que o usuário de *frameworks* tende a fazer mais atrocidades no código. E no momento que o *framework* começa expor suas limitações, enormes gambiarras são feitas. Muitas vezes porque a pessoa precisa fazer algo que ele só permite com muita personalização, mais do que deveria.
- É muito comum a pessoa escolher o *framework* errado, porque para fazer a escolha ideal precisa de um conhecimento que a pessoa não tem, e talvez não queira ter. E é comum que o ideal para o que a pessoa precisa de fato não existe.
- Frequentemente o *framework* é bem mais pesado e consome bem mais recursos. [Ele é uma abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201063/101) e isso é sempre uma vantagem e desvantagem. Alguns chegam causar prejuízos bem visíveis, outros só aumenta o custo que parecerá normal.
- Há casos que eles se tornam problemáticos ou são abandonados, e você vai junto.
- Já vi gente usando o *framework* sem preocupações com a licença e estar usando algo de um jeito pirata sem saber :)

Aliás, [sabe o que é um *framework*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

---

<sup>*</sup>No começo é lindo, vai bem, tudo parece certo, funciona, daí pra frente começam aparecer os problemas e descamba e você se arrepende da decisão de ter começado, mas já que está lá muitas vezes acaba indo até o fim sofrendo todo o percurso. Quando você ainda não conhece o todo, só viu o marketing, opiniões tendenciosas, só o simples e fácil que dá certo e a capa e até a página 3 de um livro, não é isso que define como será toda sua experiência, esse início é feito pra te pegar por isso é caprichado, o resto não costuma ser.