# Quais são os pilares da programação orientada à objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software

Em geral, eu já vi alguns lugares dizendo que a programação orientada a objetos tem 3 pilares fundamentais, em outros eu vi dizendo que são 4 pilares.

- Quantos e quais são os pilares da programação orientada à objetos?
- Como esses pilares se relacionam?
- Eles são os mesmos para todas as linguagens que dão suporte a Orientação à objetos?

Comment: Relacionado: [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13380/64969) (seção de orientação a objetos)

Comment: Mais diretamente relacionado: [Significado da terminologia: “Orientado a objeto”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88685/64969)

Comment: Outra relacionada: [POO é igual em todas as linguagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213951/64969)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Você está perguntando pra quem? [Há quem discorde](http://wiki.c2.com/?NobodyAgreesOnWhatOoIs).

[image: ALan Kay e Bjarne Stroustroup discordam do que é OOP]

> Quantos e quais são os pilares da programação orientada à objetos?

A maior parte da literatura disponível cita quatro, os três que são mais ou menos universais são:

- **Herança**

  É a capacidade de um objeto ser idealizado baseado em outro objeto.
- **Polimorfismo**

  É a capacidade de um objeto se passar por outro em determinada circunstância, desde que eles sejam compatíveis.
- **Encapsulamento**

  É a capacidade do objeto juntar tudo em uma coisa só, em geral acaba por ocultar os detalhes de implementação expondo só o que deve ser acessado publicamente, mas estritamente falando isto é *information hiding* e de alguma forma é abstração também.

A maioria ainda aceita a **abstração** que é a capacidade de expressar algo em termos gerais, sem uma especificidade, isolado do que não importa naquele contexto. Nem todos concordam com isso porque parece ser apenas a soma do encapsulamento e do polimorfismo.

Outros dizem que é um pouco diferente. É verdade que os três primeiros são mecanismos bem concretos e a abstração não é tanto assim, então faz algum sentido. Eu já não tenho tanta certeza sobre essa frase quando escrevi isso. Há uma possibilidade de no fundo todos esses conceitos serem conceitos abstratos e não concretos, alguns se confundem com mecanismos concretos. Qual é o mecanismo concreto do encapsulamento? Botar algo como `private`? Mas isso é *information hiding* e não o encapsulamento em si. Esse é um mecanismo que atende ao objetivo do encapsulamento.

Algumas pessoas acham que ter um `abstract` na linguagem é a abstração, mas não é bem assim. Isso ajuda, a interface não deixa de ser uma abstração, mas o mecanismo em si é da herança ou polimorfismo.

Em um ponto mais conceitual a abstração está mais próxima do encapsulamento já que a abstração é esconder o mecanismo concreto, é esconder o detalhe da implementação.

Alguns ainda citam alguns outros mecanismos como a sobrecarga de operadores, mas há quem diga que isto é só o polimorfismo com a abstração e quem sabe até o encapsulamento.

Já vi até outros mecanismos sendo citados, mas é bem mais raro.

O meu entendimento é que esses mecanismos principais devem estar presentes, todos eles, para dizer que é orientado a objeto. Quando apenas um ou dois deles estão presentes o código vale para outros paradigmas. E sempre achei a herança fundamental. Só encapsular e deixar polimórfico existe em outros paradigmas.

Por outro lado eu cedi ao que muitos falam que o encapsulamento, na forma como está definido, é a melhor definição da orientação a objeto, porque ela faz tudo que se refere a este objeto estar junto, é ele que faz com que o acesso seja sempre só podendo ser feito partindo do objeto.

Ainda acho que a classe por si só não define que algo é orientado a objeto, assim como seja possível ser orientado a objeto sem classe. A forma como a classe é montada é que definirá o que é OO ou não.

## Outras definições de orientação a objeto

Há literatura mais conceitual, em geral falando mais do *design* orientado a objeto, que nem considera esses mecanismos. Alguns são vagos e deixam margem à interpretação. Essas literaturas não focam no reuso de código, na abstração do mundo real em código, nas facilidades das linguagens, nos mecanismos.

Há até quem defina a orientação a objeto como colocar o objeto como foco e o mecanismo mais óbvio disto é você dizer quem é o objeto e depois indicar o que deseja fazer com ele, ou seja, `print(objeto)` não é OOP, `objeto.print()` é. Eu acho simples e vago demais, mas parece que isso é o que mais define o assunto.

> Como esses pilares se relacionam?

Eles não precisam ter uma relação direta, mas podem. Toda herança envolve subtipo, e o polimorfismo mais tradicional tem a ver com subtipo. Existe herança sem fazer subtipo, mas não é comum, com *mixin* por exemplo. É possível fazer subtipo mesmo sem herança. Muitas linguagens que não são consideradas orientadas a objeto fazem isto, falta a herança para dizerem que ela é OO.

O encapsulamento é algo bem mais ortogonal, ele não é necessário para os outros conceitos e ele não depende que os outros existam.

A abstração sem encapsulamento e polimorfismo, se dá de uma outra forma, possível, mas diferente. A não ser que esteja falando em [abstração de forma geral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23103/101), aí é muito simples, mas eu entendo que em OO o conceito tem uma definição mais estrita.

> Eles são os mesmos para todas as linguagens que dão suporte a Orientação à objetos?

Uma coisa que eu já falei antes e vou repetir, programar orientado a objeto nada tem a ver com linguagens. É verdade que algumas proveem facilidades para programar OO, mas isso não é algo obrigatório, então esses pilares existem para o código ser orientado a objeto, se a linguagem possui mecanismos facilitadores e você não os usa, ou se a linguagem não possui os facilitadores, mas usa os pilares é o que define se o código é orientado a objeto ou não.

Já [respondi uma pergunta com muito mais detalhes sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101). E tenho a impressão que até é duplicata.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ainda não deu pra terminar, mas quem negativou pode me falar o que está errado pra eu consertar qdo terminar.

Answer (score 2):

Os pilares são Abstração, Encapsulamento, Herança e Polimorfismo.

**Abstração**

É a capacidade de representar o mundo real em código, seja em classes e/ou interfaces e de criar um conjunto de rotinas capazes de serem reutilizadas para complementar outras, com seus detalhes de implementação ocultos de quem vai usar.

Envolve a implementação da lógica necessária para execução do código. Só que de forma “oculta” de quem usa. Pois quem usa, só precisa saber o que as classes/interfaces fazem, não como fazem. Este pilar é também considerado uma extensão do Encapsulamento.

***Aviso Importante:** Abstração não consiste necessariamente em criar uma classe abstrata.*

**Encapsulamento**

Mecanismo usado para esconder atributos e detalhes de implementação dos dados passados para a instância da classe. Garantindo que o acesso a dados ocorra apenas através de métodos públicos, impedindo que eles sejam alterados em tempo de execução de fora da classe.

Sabe o que é interessante no encapsulamento? É que ele é uma extensão da abstração!
Por que? Porque quando aplicado ele garante que só a própria classe conheça os detalhes de implementação e disponibilize apenas o que é possível fazer com os dados da classe como dito na definição anteriormente.

E como que aplica o encapsulamento na prática mesmo? Simples: Tornando os atributos privados ou protegidos através dos modificadores de acesso ou visibilidade “private” e “protected” e criando métodos que retornem estes atributos apenas.

***Aviso Importante:** O encapsulamento em herança pode até ser “violado”, mas somente pelas classes derivadas (subclasses/filhas) , pois a visibilidade pode estar definida como protegida (protected), não como privada (private).*

**Herança**

É uma das formas de relacionar classes/objetos e/ou compartilhar lógica de implementação.

Comumente utilizada para permitir o reuso das características (atributos) e comportamentos (métodos ) que são comuns para coisas que tem algum tipo de parentesco.

Esse tipo relação é comumente expressada como “classe pai e classe filha”, “Super Classe e Subclasse”, “Super Classe e Classe Derivada” e também como “é um(a) alguma coisa”.

***Aviso Importante:** A herança não é a única forma de criar relacionamento entre classes. Existem outras formas como Associação, Composição e Agregação. Mas aqui, apenas a herança será abordada. Pois ela é considerada um dos pilares da orientação a objetos, as outras são consideradas técnicas de relacionamento entre classes.*

**Polimorfismo**

É o mecanismo que permite que duas ou mais classes que herdam comportamentos (métodos) através de herança, se comportem de forma diferente.
Ou seja, métodos com o mesmo nome podem executar códigos e lógicas opostas, parecidas, complementares ou completamente diferentes mesmo!

E isso pode ser feito de duas formas: Estática ou Dinâmica.

**Polimorfismo na forma estática (Sobrecarga — Overload)**

O polimorfismo na forma estática é também muito conhecido como “sobrecarga” ou para os mais íntimos como “overload”.

Isso permite a existência de vários métodos com o mesmo nome mas com quantidade, tipos e/ou ordem de parâmetros levemente diferentes.

Para aplicá-lo é necessário apenas criar outro método com o mesmo nome e uma quantidade de parâmetros diferentes, ordens diferentes ou tipos diferentes (ou não).

**Polimorfismo na forma dinâmica(Sobreposição, Reescrita — Override)**

Já o polimorfismo na forma forma dinâmica é também muito conhecido como “sobreposição”, “reescrita” ou para os mais íntimos “override”.

Diferente da sobrecarga (forma dinâmica), na sobreposição é necessário que os métodos tenham exatamente o mesmo nome, tipo de retorno e quantidade de parâmetros.

Para aplicá-lo, basta criar outro método com o mesmo nome, tipo e retorno, não precisa necessariamente ter parâmetros. A implementação de sua lógica que deve ser diferente.

Inclusive, ela pode ser complementada com o método da classe base (pai/herdada) caso ele já tenha implementação (Olha só como abstração pode ser complementada, lembra?)

Este conteúdo foi extraído do artigo que escrevi sobre o tema.

Você pode obter mais detalhes com exemplos práticos [neste link aqui](https://kaiqueprazeres.medium.com/os-4-pilares-da-orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos-com-exemplos-pr%C3%A1ticos-91697976a618).

**Referências**

- *WEISFELD, Matt. The Object-Oriented Thought Process. 5. ed. San Francisco, Ca: Addison-Wesley Professional, 2019.*
- *CARDELLI, L.; WEGNER, P. On Understanding Types, Data Abstraction, and Polymorphism. ACM Computing Surveys (CSUR). vol.17, pag. 471–524.
  1985.*