# Classe, superclasse e subclasse

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, herança, subclasse, superclasse

Em relação a herança por reutilização de código no C# tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Qual é a diferença entre **classes**, **superclasses** e **subclasses**? Isso altera alguma coisa ao fazer a reutilização de código?

## Dados Adicionais:

[Significado da terminologia: "Orientado a objeto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88546/significado-da-terminologia-orientado-a-objeto)

[Quais são os pilares da programação orientada à objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215679/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-pilares-da-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-%C3%A0-objetos)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Herança é um recurso das linguagens de programação orientadas a objeto que permite a definição de uma classe base que, por sua vez, fornece uma funcionalidade específica (dados e comportamento), e a definição de classes derivadas que herdam ou substituem essa funcionalidade. A **superclasse** é àquela que é herdada por uma sub classe.

C# e .NET oferecem suporte apenas à **herança única**. Ou seja, uma classe pode herdar apenas de uma única classe. No entanto, a **herança é transitiva**, o que permite que você defina uma hierarquia de herança para um conjunto de tipos. Em outras palavras, o tipo D pode herdar do tipo C, que herda do tipo B, que herda do tipo de classe base A. Como a herança é transitiva, os membros do tipo A estão disponíveis ao tipo D.

Nem todos os membros de uma classe base são herdados por classes derivadas. Os membros a seguir não são herdados:

- Construtores estáticos, que inicializam os dados estáticos de uma classe.
- Construtores de instância, que você chama para criar uma nova instância da classe. Cada classe deve definir seus próprios construtores.
- Finalizadores, que são chamados pelo coletor de lixo do tempo de execução para destruir as instâncias de uma classe.

Enquanto todos os outros membros de uma classe base são herdados por classes derivadas, o fato de serem visíveis ou não depende de sua acessibilidade. A acessibilidade de um membro afeta sua visibilidade para classes derivadas da seguinte maneira:

- Membros Privados são visíveis apenas em classes derivadas que estão aninhadas em sua classe base. Caso contrário, eles não são visíveis em classes derivadas. No exemplo a seguir, A.B é uma classe aninhada derivada de A, e C deriva de A. O campo A.value privado fica visível em A.B. No entanto, se você remover os comentários do método C.GetValue e tentar compilar o exemplo, ele produzirá um erro do compilador CS0122: "'A.value' está inacessível devido ao seu nível de proteção".

  ```
  using System;

  public class A 
  {
     private int value = 10;

     public class B : A
     { 
         public int GetValue()
         {
             return this.value;
         }     
     }
  }


  public class Examplo
  {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          var b = new A.B();
          Console.WriteLine(b.GetValue());
      }
  }
  // O exemplo retorna a saída :10
  ```
- Membros Protegidos são visíveis apenas em classes derivadas.
- Membros Internos são visíveis apenas em classes derivadas localizadas no mesmo assembly que a classe base. Eles não são visíveis em classes derivadas localizadas em um assembly diferente da classe base.
- Membros Públicos são visíveis em classes derivadas e fazem parte da interface pública da classe derivada. Membros herdados público podem ser chamados como se tivessem sido definidos na classe derivada.

FONTE: [Microsoft DOCs Tutorial de Herança](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance)

Answer (score 9):

Classe é o termo geral, é um modelo da estrutura de dados, especificamente em C# é sempre um tipo por referência. A herança é justamente criar uma classe que é baseada em outra classe já existente reusando o código já escrito.

Superclasse é aquela classe que será derivada, é a classe mãe ou base como também é chamada.

Subclasse é a classe derivada, é a classe filha que foi herdada de uma superclasse.

```
public class SuperClasse {}
public class Subclasse : SuperClasse {}
```

O exemplo ajuda entender mas não é dos melhores porque esta subclasse também pode ser uma superclasse então poderia fazer:

```
public class NovaSubClasse : SubClasse {} //aqui SubClasse não deixa de ser uma superclasse.
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/SuperSubClass.cs).

Comment: Quando seria ideal utiliza-los?

Comment: @RenatoSilva Acho que está confundindo o que é isto. É um conceito abstrato, não é uma ferramenta concreta, basta fazer herança e estará usando super e subclasse. Quando usar herança é um pouco mais complicado, dá para escrever um livro sobre isto. Mas pode-se dizer para não usar até que seja absolutamente necessário. Pode começar por aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=heran%c3%a7a Se nada atender faça uma pergunta específica sobre isto.