# Por que esconder a implementação de uma classe?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, encapsulamento

Este é o conceito em que eu já me esforcei para entender, mas nunca consegui plenamente.

Vou pegar esse trecho de um livro do Deitel para ilustrar:

> É uma melhor engenharia de software definir funções-membro fora da
>   definição de classe. Essa prática assegura que os programadores não
>   escrevam um código-cliente que dependa da sua implementação da classe.
>   Se eles precisassem fazer isso, o código-cliente provavelmente
>   'quebraria' se a implementação da classe fosse alterada.

Não consigo entender como seria possível para o cliente escrever um código que dependesse da implementação da classe, visto que as variáveis locais do método e os campos `private` da classe são inacessíveis de qualquer maneira.

Alguém poderia me ilustrar um exemplo prático de código em que isso poderia acontecer? Um exemplo de método de biblioteca exposto no qual o usuário iria usar algo específico da implementação desse método no seu código e em seguida uma possível alteração dessa implementação pelo criador da biblioteca que quebraria o código do cliente. Preciso de um exemplo para conseguir entender. Já vi milhões de explicações conceituais, mas nenhuma fez sentido para mim.

Acho até, na minha visão de leigo, mais interessante deixar visível as implementações já que o programador pode ter curiosidade em saber como tal método funciona, do mesmo modo que alguém  pode querer saber por que ao apertar um botão de rádio, a estação muda, por exemplo.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 7):

Isto tem a ver com o [princípio Open-Close](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) do [SOLID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101). Sempre que você coloca um comportamento público, ou mesmo protegido em uma classe e permite que esta classe seja herdada você passa ter uma responsabilidade com aquilo, qualquer alteração tem que ser muito bem pensada para que as classes herdadas não sejam afetadas por uma alteração que você faça na classe.

De certa forma tem a ver também com o [princípio de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) já que você não precisa só respeitar o contrato estabelecido em [superclasse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/234063/101), precisa garantir que o comportamento é o esperado por quem herdou aquilo.

Mas se você mudar de um jeito que não quebre algo então está tudo ok.

Portanto quanto menos coisas colocar dentro da classe maior a chance de de algo quebrar. Uma forma é colocar certas funcionalidades em [classes utilitárias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/101), outra é criar [membros estáticos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101) na própria classe. Uma forma que já ajuda um pouco é ter [membros não virtuais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151243/101), assim pelo menos esses membros não podem ser herdados. Mas o mais eficaz é colocar fora porque aí tem mais liberdade de mexer como quiser.

Um dos problemas ocorre quando você adiciona um novo método. Imagine que a classe descendente pode ter um método dela com uma [assinatura idêntica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101). Qual ele deve executar? As coisas começam a ficar menos previsíveis.

Note que tudo que é privado não tem a menor importância. Talvez a dúvida tenha surgido daí, o que o livro fala é sobre os membros públicos apenas. Na parte privada faça como quiser, a única responsabilidade é com a própria classe que você deve ter controle total. Então tudo não fez sentido até agora porque estava interpretando errado o conceito.

Deixar visível o fonte nada tem a ver com deixar público. Quer deixar o fonte aberto, deixe, isso nada tem a ver com o conceito de visibilidade dos membros de um tipo que é algo interno do código e não de como você gerencia o projeto como um todo. [Diminuir a visibilidade não é sobre proteger o fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189162/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Refleti bastante sobre o seu post e os links listados nele e ainda assim me parece meio obscuro. Entendi o conceito de Open Closed, mas ainda não entendo por que quando analisamos um arquivo de biblioteca não vemos as implementações dos seus métodos. Se a classe está bloqueada para edição e habilitada para extensão, qual o problema em ter sua implementação exposta, visto que não pode ser mudada e apenas sobrescrita?

Comment: O problema é que você está supondo coisas que ninguém está dizendo. As classes podem ser editadas. Só que deve ser feito com cuidado. Muita coisa não pode fazer. Se você aplicar o O/C de forma fundamentalista, como muitos fazem, de fato tanto faz, mas os pragmáticos sabem que isto é inviável, então fazem as classes mais limpas assim não precisam ser fundamentalistas. A questão foi colocada pelos pragmáticos. Fundamentalistas vão pensar como você está pensando agora. Fundamentalistas nunca entenderam OOP, mas eles juram que só eles entenderam. Afinal são fundamentalistas, faz parte.

Comment: De fato, devo estar vendo a questão sob um ângulo errado. Só com o amadurecimento de todos esses conceitos ao longo tempo é que talvez eu olhe de uma forma correta e finalmente consiga entender o que acredito ser algo relativamente simples. Deixarei a questão em aberto por enquanto e voltarei outro dia, com uma concepção mais apurada sobre o assunto. Agradeço a ajuda, de qualquer forma.

Comment: @EduardoM se achar que deve, veja o que pode fazer no [tour].