# Quais são as principais diferenças entre programação orientada a protótipos e programação orientada a classes?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, característica-linguagem, independente-de-linguagem, protótipo

Depois de ter aprendido um pouco mais sobre JavaScript, percebi que, mesmo tendo uma construção [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), classes (de fato, como em C# ou Java) não existem no JavaScript. Isso não passa de açúcar sintático para a programação orientada a protótipos da linguagem.

Já sei [como a programação prototípica funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/69296), mas não sei de fato as diferenças entre ela e uma programação orientada a classes (verdadeiras, como em Java ou C#).

Então, a pergunta é:

- Quais são as principais diferenças entre a orientação a objetos via *protótipos* e a orientação a objetos via *classes*?
- Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um desses padrões?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom, a pergunta não foca na implementação específica, como é a de JavaScript, então não falarei tanto dos pontos que JS escolheu assim, ainda que seja a implementação mais popular dessa forma de orientação a objeto.

Vou começar pedindo para você ler [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Não existindo a classe o modelo é o próprio objeto. E isso pode ser considerado vantagem ou desvantagem já que não precisa escrever o modelo, escreve direto um objeto, o que é mais simples, mas muda um pouco o modelo mental, que fere um dos pontos principais que a orientação a objeto foi criada que é pensar sobre o que é aquele objeto.

Uma desvantagem clara é que qualquer meta informação precisa estar dentro do próprio objeto, em alguns casos carregados em todos objetos ou em objetos específicos. Isso é claramente menos eficiente. A flexibilidade cobra um preço.

É bem flexível modificar o protótipo da maneira que for melhor para casa caso, mas ao mesmo tempo torna os contratos mais frágeis. Tudo é mais fácil nele, inclusive cometer erros.

As linguagens que optaram pela classe, em geral, são de tipagem estática e prezam mais pelos contratos, afinal a classe (real) é um contrato rígido. Nada impede dessas linguagens terem uma forma de protótipo ou classe falsa de forma mais ou menos conveniente, e assim dar mais flexibilidade também, da mesma forma que elas podem dar dinamismo opcional para tipagem. Quando opta-se por não ter classe fica faltando elementos e essas linguagens nunca podem ter as mesmas características que as que optaram pela classe.

O protótipo torna muito difícil manter a tipagem estática, cada alteração no objeto tem potencial de mudar seu tipo.

A classe tem a ver com ser mais explícito. Com o protótipo tudo pode acontecer, você tem que estar mais preparado, o que é curioso porque a facilidade que ele dá cobra um preço que torna mais difícil, e se você não souber o que está fazendo terá que contar com sorte, o compilador pode fazer pouco por você.

A classe falsa já pode ajudar muito, que é o que JavaScript, e principalmente TypeScript, fizeram. Ela dá informações que ajudam o compilador tomar decisões e muitos dos problemas citados são resolvidos. Mas ela não torna o objeto mais eficiente, ele ainda tem o peso de um protótipo, conta com a infraestrutura para dar flexibilidade não usada (naquele ponto). É o mesmo que colocar tipos estáticos nas variáveis em linguagens como JS, Python, PHP, Ruby ou outra, ajuda dar robustez, mas o preço do objeto dinâmico continua lá.

Então podemos dizer que isso tem um pouco a ver com o velho problema sobre [o que é orientação a objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101) e tem ligações com [as duas escolas desse paradigma secundário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101) ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13388/101)). O protótipo agrada mais ao fãs do Alan Kay e a classe agrada mais os fãs do Bjarne Stroustrup.

Pra mim as diferenças, vantagens e desvantagens são quase as mesmas da tipagem dinâmica e estática. Ela não te cobra pra entrar, te cobra por tudo o que faz depois.

[Tabela da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#summary_of_differences):

| Categoria | Com base em classe | Com base em protótipo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Classe vs. instância | Classe e instância são entidades distintas | Todos os objetos podem herdar de outro objeto |
| Definição | Defina uma classe com uma definição de classe; instancie uma classe com métodos construtores | Defina e crie um conjunto de objetos com funções construtoras |
| Criação de um novo objeto | Crie um único objeto com o operador `new` | Idem |
| Construção da hierarquia de objetos | Construa uma hierarquia de objetos usando definições de classe para definir subclasses de classes existentes | Construa uma hierarquia de objetos atribuindo um objeto como o protótipo associado a uma função de construtor |
| Modelo de herança | Herde propriedades seguindo a cadeia de classes | Herde propriedades seguindo a cadeia de protótipo |
| Extensão das propriedades | A definição de classe especifica todas as propriedades de todas as instâncias de uma classe. Não é possível adicionar propriedades dinamicamente em tempo de execução | A função construtora ou protótipo especifica um conjunto inicial de propriedades. Pode adicionar ou remover propriedades dinamicamente para objetos individuais ou para todo o conjunto de objetos |

Acho que vale a leitura de [JavaScript é uma linguagem Orientada a Objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141645/101). E [Existe classe em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108548/101).

Para mais aprofundamento quase sempre as melhores fontes estão na [mãe das wikis](https://wiki.c2.com/?ClassesPrototypesComparison).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

A herança prototípica é um modelo bastante simples de reutilização de código, o código pode ser reutilizado de maneira direta e ajuda-nos a reduzir a redundância.

As desvantagens são a falta de variáveis privadas e protegidas e os tipos não seguros.