# Por que ao acessar a propriedade de uma classe só preciso usar um cifrão ("$this->propriedade" em vez de "$this->$propriedade")?

Tags: php, classes, variáveis

Por que não precisa colocar `$` na variável `nameHolder` no retorno do método `showHolder()` e quando coloca `$nameHolder` no retorno diz que a variável não está definida?

```php
class Account
{
    private string $cpfHolder;
    private string $nameHolder;
    private float $balance = 0;

    public function showHolder(): string 
    {
        return $this->$nameHolder; // não funciona.
        return $this->nameHolder; // funciona.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP nunca foi muito bem pensada. Quando criaram as variáveis inventaram que elas deveriam ser precedidas por `$` na sua sintaxe. Embora isso seja um facilitador para algumas situações, não é para todas, e dificulta a maioria dos usos. Isso nunca deveria ter sido criado assim.

Quando criaram uma variável dentro de outra variável acharam que podiam consertar isso, ou mesmo que não era necessário duplicar esse esforço errado que já fazia, então acharam melhor não colocar assim tornando a linguagem inconsistente e estranha porque a mesma variável usa o símbolo ou não dependendo de onde é usada.

O símbolo na verdade era para indicar uma expressão a ser tratada de forma diferente, então ele deveria ser usado só em contexto que isso faz sentido. Ao mesmo tempo deveria ser usado para casos que não é uma variável, por isso jamais deveria estar atrelado ao nome.

Se já tem o `$` na variável principal não deve usar de novo. Então ficou uma regra de exceção que você tem que saber e usar.

Porém tem uma outra questão. Não existem classes no PHP. Sim, o que você está vendo é uma ilusão, assim como é em PHP e quase todas linguagens de tipagem dinâmica. Elas usam protótipos, ou seja, usam objetos (geralmente alguma forma de *array* associativo que já podem até existir na linguagem) para armazenar os membros que o objeto teria. A sintaxe de classe é apenas *sugar* para ficar mais fácil para as pessoas que não gostam ou não entendem os [protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/480981/101).

Então o seu código na verdade é isto:

```
$this['nameHolder']
```

Está vendo o `$` no segundo nome? E abaixo?

```
$this[$nameHolder]
```

São coisas diferentes, não? E são válidas, certo? Mesmo que não saiba, é valido sim, você está substituindo um valor por uma variável, como deveria poder em todos lugares (em PHP teve uma época que não podia, e eles arrumaram isso com o tempo, não sei se ainda tem algum lugar que não dá).

O código acima faz sentido, mas quando quer usa a classe quer outro tipo de sintaxe, e quer usar algo que foi consagrado em linguagens de tipagem estática. Mais ainda, segue a tendência de PHP de dar contratos fortes para tudo, portanto uma classe deveria ser vista como algo que não pode ser alterada ou acessado de forma dinâmica, que é isso que está fazendo.

Claro que isso tiraria a flexibilidade que eles preferiram manter, mas tornam a linguagem sem identidade e no fim não dá vantagem que pretendem ter dos contratos fortes.

Então eles mantiveram a possibilidade se usar a variável no lugar do nome literal da membro do objeto e dar a flexibilidade. Eu discordo da decisão até por ficar esquisito, mas principalmente por quebrar o contrato forte que espera de uma classe.

Então por que não deu certo se isso é aceito? O "não funciona" significa apenas que não tem um membro sem nome. E porque está referenciando um membro sem nome? Porque `$nameHolder`, que não tem qualquer valor, é uma variável que não existe, e PHP aceita uma variável que não existe como se existisse, pegando um valor não existente.

Note que precisaria criar uma variável local para funcionar. Até poderia usar o campo, mas aí ele precisaria ser referenciado com o `$this`, o que fica mais confuso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A pessoa que votou negativo pode dizer qual é o erro na resposta. Pode comentar ou dar uma resposta. Caso contrário saberemos que é só desgosto mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

`$this->$nameHolder` não funciona da forma que você espera por causa das [*variable variables*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (que em português foi traduzido como "[variáveis variáveis](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php)").

Basicamente, você pode usar uma variável que contém o nome de outra variável, e obter o valor desta diretamente. Por exemplo:

```php
$nome = 'Fulano';

$x = 'nome';
echo $$x; // Fulano
```

O código acima imprime "Fulano". Isso porque a expressão `$$x` é avaliada como "a variável cujo nome é o valor de `$x`". Como o valor de `$x` é a string "nome", então `$$x` é o mesmo que `$nome`, por isso o resultado é a string "Fulano".

---

Isso também ocorre se usar o `$` para acessar a propriedade de uma classe.
Ou seja, `$this->$nameHolder` irá procurar pela propriedade cujo nome é o valor da variável `$nameHolder`. Exemplo:

```php
class Account {
    private $nameHolder = 'Fulano';
    private $balance = 0;
 
    public function test() {
        $nameHolder = 'balance';
        echo "Balance:". $this->$nameHolder. "\n";
        echo "Holder:". $this->nameHolder. "\n";
    }
}

$c = new Account();
$c->test();
```

No primeiro `echo`, a expressão `$this->$nameHolder` pegará o valor da variável `$nameHolder` (que apesar de ter o mesmo nome da propriedade da classe, não é a mesma variável). O valor é a string "balance", então a expressão pega o valor da propriedade que tem esse nome (ou seja, é o mesmo que `$this->balance`).

Já no segundo `echo` estou pegando a propriedade `nameHolder`. A saída do código acima é:

```
Balance:0
Holder:Fulano
```

O que acontece no seu código é que não há nenhuma variável `$nameHolder` definida, portanto ele não consegue avaliar a expressão `$this->$nameHolder` (ele tenta pegar o valor de `$nameHolder`, mas como essa variável não existe, dá erro).

Comment: Não tinha visto.... :D. Não sei se está dentro do escopo da resposta mas as "variáveis variáveis" tem dois dois casos especiais que não podem ser referenciados o `$this` e as variáveis superglobais.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Acho que se a pergunta fosse sobre como funcionam as *variable variables*, aí faria sentido falar de todos os casos. Mas aqui é sobre um caso particular apenas, não sei se precisa se aprofundar tanto...

Answer (score -4):

O $this já faz isso! Ela diz, variável essa, poderia ser, essa variável, só que no lugar de variável é informado $, grosso modo e "entedível" pra leigos é isso!