# Modificadores de acesso em PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tem algum sentido eu criar uma classe, definir três funções, duas públicas e uma privada, e fazer com que a função privada seja acessada através do método público?

Exemplo:

```
    class Pessoa {

      private $nome;
      private $idade;
      private $sexo;

      private function falar() {

       echo("Falando...");

    } 


      public function correr() {

       echo ("Correndo...");

    }

      public function mostrarMétodo() {

      $this->falar();

    }
}
```

- Qual a vantagem/desvantagem disso? (Se possível, exemplo real)
- Outra pergunta, por que deixar o atributo privado (`private $nome`), e acessar através do método?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

> Tem algum sentido eu criar uma classe, definir três funções, duas públicas e uma privada, e fazer com que a função privada seja acessada através do método público?

No **geral** faz muito sentido, métodos públicos fazem parte de um contrato, da API, é o que você deixa os outros acessarem no seu objeto, já métodos privados são detalhes de implementação, são partes que não quer que fiquem conhecidas e acessíveis fora do objeto, é algo que você pode mudar quando quiser e não tem compromisso em manter sempre assim, não faz parte do contrato do objeto, é só para facilitar a organização do seu código interno.

**Especificamente** no exemplo não faz sentido, pelo menos acho, só posso afirmar vendo os requisitos. Intuitivamente eu acho que a `fala` deveria ser pública, e `mostrarMétodo()` parece só exemplo mal feito, assim parece fazer mais sentido:

```
public function falar() {
     if (!$mudo) articulaFala();
}

private function articulaFala() {
     echo("Falando...");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Private.php).

Assim faz sentido? Depende do requisito, pode ser que esse método auxiliar privado não seja necessário, só o caso concreto para saber. Por isso sempre digo que programar não é seguir regras, não é juntar um monte de peça de lego, é entender o que está fazendo.

[image: Monte de peças lego soltas]

> Qual a vantagem/desvantagem disso? (Se possível, exemplo real)

Quando vejo este tipo de pergunta já sei que a pessoa começou aprender OOP sem ter aprendido básico da programação, ou seja, está criando acabamento na casa que não tem alicerce. Percebo que a maioria das pessoas criam funções o tempo todo e não sabem porque estão fazendo aquilo, ela viu uma receita de bolo que faz assim e faz igual. Somente entendendo o básico da programação é que pode programar corretamente. Precisa entender porque quebrar o código em partes, e quais seriam essas partes, o que é pouco, o que é muito, que ganho você tem com isto. Estamos falando de [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), de [abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23103/101).

Aí dá pra responder porque deve ser público ou privado. Ser público é fácil, é porque você precisa que aquilo seja acessível por objetos externos, só estes métodos devem ser públicos, se não precisa, não faça, tudo que é público vira contrato, você tem que cumprir pra sempre, não pode mudar nada que quebre outros códigos. Tem que evitar para que tenha [boa coesão e baixo acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101). E o privado deve esconder tudo o que não precisa fazer parte do contrato.

Estou declamando a regrinha básica. Quem realmente sabe programar sabe a hora de usar um ou outro e depende de muito estudo, muita prática correta, muita capacidade de evolução, de se atentar aos detalhes e querer fazer o certo, algo que é bem raro hoje em dia. Por sorte hoje quando temos dúvidas podemos perguntar para pessoas aleatórias na internet, e em alguns casos achamos pessoas que conseguem avaliar de forma correta e podem nos ensinar se fizemos certo ou não, desde que conseguimos fazer a pergunta do jeito certo fornecendo todos os detalhes possíveis. O problema é que como não sabemos bem sobre o assunto temos dificuldade em avaliar se aquilo é certo ou não, e vivemos sempre dentro de um [Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect). Claro, algumas pessoas nem querer aprender de verdade, só conhecer as receitas de bolo.

Só tem desvantagem se você fizer errado, se não atende o que precisa ou é o chamado *overengineering*.

Exemplos pela metade ou abstratos não ajudam muito aqui e como eu não tenho programado em PHP, principalmente não uso OOP em uma linguagem de *script* (OO neste tipo de linguagem não faz sentido, não sei porque as pessoas fazem isto, exceto por estar seguindo a moda), nem sei de exemplos prontos bons que demonstram isto (existe, só não está no meu dia a dia).

> Outra pergunta, por que deixar o atributo privado(`private $nome`, e acessar através do método?

Isto [já foi amplamente respondido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101). Mas em resumo não faça nada que você não possa justificar porque está fazendo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, estou aprendendo agora OPP e não tive muitas orientações, aprendi LP comandos básicos (if, else, else if, switch, array, etc) e não estruturas de dados avançada então eu acho que com os erros que nós aprendemos... Claro que é minha opinião, mas considero sua resposta como válida. De fato, eu estou seguindo video-aulas em diversos canais, então não sei se está certo ou não, aliás, isso é relativo...

Comment: Como você possui experiência na área (além dos prêmios MVC), poderia me auxiliar com a ajuda de livros, videos, canais etc? Isso já ajuda bastante os desenvolvedores novos que estão entraram para o mercado ou zonas de estudo...

Comment: Eu não gosto muito de indicar essas coisas de forma geral, porque não é só indicar, preciso fazer uma resenha completa, mostra que tem pontos negativos, pq se eu assinar embaixo de algo que tem problemas eu estou ajudando a pessoa ter problemas. EU o farei sim, isto está na minha ToDo list, mas quando farei eu não sei, falta tempo, me segue nas redes que uma hora eu posto algum.

Answer (score 3):

Faz todo sentido, ao projetar uma classe o ideal é definir métodos (funções) como sendo comportamentos de uma determinada entidade e não simplesmente vários getters e setters para modificar atributos. Um método pode encapsular um conjunto de regras e validações para que defina de forma consistente os atributos da classe, considerando que um método publico pode executar diversos outros métodos privados internos com o intuito de isolar suas implementações e garantir que esses métodos internos não sejam chamados por fora da classe.

Answer (score -3):

Boa tarde,

> Qual a vantagem/desvantagem disso? (Se possível, exemplo real)

Isso permite que você mantenha seguras as operações criticas do seu sistema, como visualizar uma senha, inserir saldo.

> por que deixar o atributo privado (private $nome), e acessar através
>   do método?

Isso evita que o atributo nome seja acessado e/ou atribuído diretamente sem qualquer validação. Imagine que você possui um atributo $saldo Esse atributo não pode ser simplesmente usando:

```
Pessoa->$saldo = 1.000.000
```

acessando através de um método você garante que todas as regras e validações necessária foram feitas

Comment: Como algo privado impediria de visualizar uma senha? Se o invasor conseguiria executar algo como `echo $obj->senha` ele poderia muito bem acessar o arquivo fonte e olhar a senha.