# Quão abstratos são ponteiros em C?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, malloc, abstração

Eu tenho uma visão, que de uns tempos pra cá me parece errada, que ponteiros em C são simplesmente e literalmente endereços de memória (inteiros representando posições diretas ou virtuais de memória).

No caso isso parte de uma noção também errada que a memória fosse uma coisa linear e acessada diretamente em suas posições absolutas. Talvez isso fosse verdade nos tempos do MS-DOS. Nunca aprendi direito essa parte.

Na verdade o sistema operacional abstrai isso para endereços relativos, iniciados em 0 (que é mapeado para um endereço absoluto qualquer, e hoje em dia rola uma história de randomização de endereço também por questão de segurança) e que vão até a um valor máximo alocado para aquele programa. Ou qualquer coisa assim.

Enfim, estou estudando aqui, mas bateu essa dúvida em relação a ponteiros. Quão abstratos eles são do ponto de vista do C? Eles **são** um número representando um endereço de memória ou somente abstrações que **expõem** indiretamente esse endereço para o programador? Acho que só expõem, porque senão bastaria usar, por exemplo, um `int` ou `long`.

E por que é relevante diferenciar um ponteiro para `char` de um para `int`, se todos eles guardam um endereço para uma posição (relativa) de memória? Por exemplo, no caso do retorno de um `malloc()`?

Uma resposta válida é portanto "Continue estudando que uma hora irá entender".

Na verdade se só me responderem que é uma abstração cuja implementação oculta alguns detalhes do programador já posso considerar respondido o que eu queria saber. Claro que detalhar a implementação seria um complemento muito interessante.

Comment: A razão para diferenciar um ponteiro para `char` de um para `int` é apenas para checagem de tipo durante a compilação. Ambos ponteiros tem a mesma representação na memória, mas não é bom saber para que tipo de dado o ponteiro está apontando ao ler/escrever o código?

Comment: Para fins de checagem de tipo na compilação acho que é uma informação útil sim. Mas na teoria eu posso burlar isso e declarar por exemplo `int *str = malloc(sizeof(char));` (ou vice-versa) que o compilador aceita, ou não? Vou fazer o teste.

Comment: Não sei as consequências disso na prática no programa, mas aceita ambos: https://ideone.com/qUsO1V

Comment: O tipo faz diferença ao se fazer aritmética de ponteiros, basicamente `&x + 1` pega o endereço de `x` e soma `sizeof x` bytes (e não 1). Também faz diferença ao se pegar o valor para o qual ele aponta. Ex: https://ideone.com/VoghTL

Comment: @hkotsubo Muito bem observado, eu não sabia/lembrava que dava diferença na matemática de ponteiros, e também na hora de recuperar o conteúdo em memória, dois ótimos motivos para ser incluído o tipo na declaração :)

Comment: Mas ainda ficou uma dúvida: internamente o tipo do dado apontado faz parte do ponteiro? Ou isso tudo é, como foi falado, para fins de resolução em compilação e depois é convertido em ponteiros "perigosos" vamos dizer assim, digo, no sentido de posições/estruturas de memória que não têm tipo do conteúdo associado?

Comment: Aí eu não sei. Eu acho que faz sentido o ponteiro ter a informação do tipo para o qual ele aponta, senão ficaria difícil fazer operações como a aritmética e a desreferenciação (*existe essa palavra?*). Mas não sei se a especificação da linguagem diz algo sobre isso (e estou com preguiça de procurar :-p)

Comment: Leitura complementar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15151377 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/1352500 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/950972 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/44345148

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podemos dizer que conceitualmente ponteiros são abstratos.

(Parágrafo escrito pelo AP, pendente eventual correção): C define o tipo de dado *pointer* como variáveis que guardam um endereço (*address*), mas deixa propositalmente em aberto, a fim de permitir maior liberdade nas implementações, o que seria esse endereço (embora seja mais frequente que queira dizer que se trata de alguma forma de endereçamento para a memória).

Na verdade quase tudo é abstrato, concreto mesmo só os elétrons excitados (o povo delira quando falo assim :D) circulando pelos elétrons estáticos em materiais dos computadores. O bit já é um conceito abstrato.

As coisas são mais abstratas ou menos abstratas, mas algum nível de abstração sempre tem, pelo menos em coisas criadas por humanos. Temos que sempre considerar níveis de abstração e não se é ou não abstrato. Até uma palavra que indica algo já é uma [abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23103/101).

Ponteiro (não só o tipo do C) é um conceito que um humano criou para dar a entender que temos uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). O mais comum é ser em memória, mas não precisar ser, temos em outros contextos, por exemplo pode-se ter um ponteiro em banco de dados (que se as pessoas soubessem fazer poderiam fazer algumas economias).

Em memória, o conceito mais usado em programação, de fato um ponteiro é representado por um endereço de memória.

Do ponto de vista abstrato (ou seja, a partir do momento em que a memória é abstraída) não importa se a memória física é linear ou não. A abstração serve justamente para isso.

Mensurar o nível de abstração nem sempre é fácil, fica subjetivo. Qual é o mínimo e o máximo de abstração? Vai de 0 a 10, ou de 0 à 100? Ou nem é assim que se mede. Não temos parâmetros para isso.

Podemos dizer que ele é [mais concreto que a referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101).

E o mecanismo é uma forma mais abstrata de acessar a memória.

Abstratamente não deveria se preocupar tanto assim como eles são implementados, mas quanto mais baixo desce o nível mais importante é saber isto.

Eu não sei se tem essa dicotomia que a pergunta parte. Ou mesmo se isso tem relevância. Mas vou tentar responder.

Mas ele existe até mesmo em Assembly, é um tipo que trata de algo que o processador entende, assim como os tipos numéricos. Dá para entender o nível de concretude? Ele é mais concreto que *string*, uma data, ou até um *array* que é mais abstrato que um ponteiro, até porque depende do ponteiro para existir.

Na forma exposta parece falar do tipo que é um *pointer*, não só do mecanismo (nota do AP: estou peguntando do tipo e do mecanismo debaixo dele). E aí a dúvida se ele seria um tipo concreto ou um [tipo abstrato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) faz sentido.

O meu entendimento é que ele é mais concreto, ele é um conceito que existe no computador, ele não é o mesmo que um `int` ou `long`. Ele não é um outro tipo composto unicamente por um inteiro, ele tem uma forma própria. Isso é o oposto do que acontece com uma data por exemplo que tem a quantidade de segundos ou frações e segundos representados como inteiros ou outro tipo numérico "concreto", ou a interação entre dados numéricos que representam anos, meses, dias e quem sabe horas, e outras frações de dias.

Um `int` pode ser interpretado como um ponteiro? Pode, mas isso é circunstancial, nem sempre isso é verdade.

## "Tipo do ponteiro"

Foi feita uma outra pergunta que é completamente diferente do que foi perguntado no título, talvez por não entender isso.

Diferenciar para o que o ponteiro está apontando nada tem a ver com o ponteiro em si. Dizer para o que ele aponta é importante para saber o tamanho que está apontando e saber até onde deve acessar aquela informação, ou até mesmo calcular a posição virtual da memória de uma estrutura sequencial (*array*).

O compilador precisa dessa informação para fazer escolhas e gerar um código adequado, e am alguns casos forçar a tipagem (nem tanto porque C tem tipagem fraca, mas algumas implementações têm opções de fortalecer a tipagem e se torna mais importante ainda).

A questão do `malloc()` é só um caso disso que acabei de falar, mas é [ortogonal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101) ao ponteiro ou seu tipo, ele não precisa saber o tamanho do ponteiro ou do seu tipo apontado.

O [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) aloca *bytes*, sempre, o `sizeof` pode ser usado para pegar o tamanho de algo. O `sizeof` pode ser usado para pegar o tamanho do ponteiro porque dependendo da arquitetura o tamanho dele é diferente. Mas não faz sentido pegar o tamanho do ponteiro de acordo com o tipo, porque o tamanho do ponteiro não muda, muda o tamanho do objeto apontado.

(Nota do AP: Este último parágrafo dá a entender que eu me referia ao endereço do ponteiro, mas na verdade fala do endereço da coisa apontada, guardado no ponteiro. Corrigi na pergunta. De qualquer forma a afirmação também é verdadeira e é interessante saber).

`sizeof char` (as pessoas usam sempre os parênteses porque acham que é uma função, mas é um operador) não faz sentido porque a especificação da linguagem diz que é garantido que é 1. Quem faz isso costuma ser terraplanista, acha que um dia pode mudar :D.

Aceitar algo não quer dizer nada, C aceita quase tudo. Alocar 1 byte (`char`) é tão aceito quanto alocar 4 bytes tipicamente (`int`, pode ser outro tamanho), mas aloca bem diferente. Isso nada tem a ver com ponteiro.

O tipo do dado completo quando usa ponteiro é "Ponteiro de alguma coisa", não é só ponteiro, nunca, e não é só o tipo. Dá para fazer um ponteiro para nada (`void`), que na prática quer dizer que é para qualquer coisa, abre-se mão do tamanho do objeto apontado.

Em C os ponteiros tendem a ser relativamente seguros, se usar certo, em Assembly é pura matemática, mas se eles foram gerados por um compilador C conforme eles funcionarão com perfeição.

Só lembrando que a especificação de C, não só nisso, é bem aberta à implementação fazer como desejar, mas na prática, é isso que expliquei aqui.

Tem complementos interessantes nos comentários acima e abaixo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Podemos considerar um terraplanismo, mas `sizeof char` não pode ser uma questão de expressar o que se quer fazer, pelo menos para fins didáticos? Por exemplo, `char *new_str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));`? É que vi um material fazendo isso.

Comment: Até pode, mas o 1 pode o mesmo, porque você só usa o 1 para isso. E só faz sentido quando é um `char` mesmo, e é muito comum usarem para dizer que é um *byte*, aí é dizer que quer algo que não é o que quer, mesmo o resultado sendo diferente. Esse exemplo é um que eu não usaria, é ruído, e capaz de ter outro problema antes desse trecho :D

Comment: _"O tamanho do ponteiro não muda, muda o tamanho do objeto apontado"._ Isso se traduz em dizer que `malloc(sizeof int*)` (ou seja qual for a sintaxe) não leva em consideração o `int`, que é o tipo para o qual o ponteiro aponta, e sim somente o fato de ser um ponteiro, cujo tamanho é basicamente determinado pela arquitetura, correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Para esse caso é isso. se você colocar `void *` dá na mesma.

Comment: _"C aceita quase tudo"._ e "_Isso nada tem a ver com ponteiro"._ Podemos dizer basicamente que `malloc` tem relação somente incidental com ponteiros então. Dizer que um ponteiro é um TAD que abstrai um endereço de memória (que já é uma abstração do sistema operacional), propositalmente permitindo invadir outros endereços, acho que mata a questão.

Comment: Sim, ele gera um ponteiro para o local que ele reservou, e só. Qualquer outra relação com ponteiro nada tem a ver com `malloc()`, **pode** ter a ver com `sizeof`. Eu não disse que é um TAD, falei o contrário.

Comment: kkkk então eu entendi tudo errado. :D E uma referência, é um TAD? Ou TADs foram citados como contra-exemplos?

Comment: Referência é algo mais complicado, mas acho que nem chega ser um TAD, referência na prática é só conceitual. Poderia ser um TAD cujo único membro é um ponteiro (ou até ter algo mais). Complica um pouco porque ela é incrustada na linguagem, mas eu diria que não é errado dizer que é um TAD disfarçado. Ponteiro tem até em Assembly.