# Qual o termo que devo utilizar em português para "dereference" um ponteiro

Tags: c, terminologia, ponteiro

Como sabem em inglês o termo *dereferencing* é utilizado para indicar o acesso ao valor guardado num endereço guardado num ponteiro ***i.e.***:

```
int valor = 10;
int *ptr = &valor;

*ptr = 20; // dereferencing
```

Eu tenho necessidade de usar este termo em português mas tenho alguma dificuldade em encontrar uma forma simples para o fazer, talvez *desreferenciar*, mas não soa particularmente bem, e parece que as pessoas não estão muito familiarizadas com isto.

A minha questão é, há algum termo *well-known* em português que possa usar?

Comment: Vejo duas possibilidades, _desreferenciar_ e _derreferenciar_ (em comparação a, por exemplo, derrabar). Teria que investigar a etimologia dos prefixos para ver se batem. A ideia do termo, no meu entendimento, é derivar ou calcular uma informação (conteúdo na memória) a partir de uma referência (que apesar de frequentemente ser tratada como um endereço de memória deve a rigor ser considerada algo abstrato apontando para alguma coisa, podendo inclusive ser uma infomação composta, por exemplo um endereço absoluto mais um delta, a depender talvez da arquitetura de memória adotada).

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/507427/357

Comment: @Piovezan agradeço a informação, e tens toda a razão nas observações que fazes, no meu caso particular é mesmo mais uma questão de terminologia, ou seja, nas minhas explicações preciso de usar este termo muitas vezes.

Comment: Da 2a edição do _Kernighan & Ritchie_ em português brasileiro: _"O operador unário * é o operador de indireção ou deferenciação"_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pessoas não estão muito familiarizadas com isso pois é de fato um conhecimento novo para muitas pessoas. É um conceito bem estrito e novo em relação ao vocabulários de linguagens faladas, também.

Por isso que, sim, nesse caso provavelmente é melhor usar uma tradução literal, ainda que soe estranha. *Desreferenciar*, *derreferenciar* (gramaticalmente mais correta na reforma ortográfica atual que *de-referenciar*), *deferenciar* (edição brasileira do Kernighan & Ritchie, os autores da linguagem).

A sugestão ai é usar uma nota de rodapé, após usar o termo adaptado, e nessa nota:

1. Colocar o termo original, em itálico.
2. Explicar o que ele *faz*, e não se preocupar muito com a etimologia da coisa.

O (2) pode parecer estranho, mas isso porque uma possível interpretação em português usa uma palavra completamente diferente: Reinterpretar ou remapear.

Um ponteiro é um ponteiro, e ainda que venha anotado do tipo, continua sendo um mero endereço de memória. Um ponteiro dereferenciado é um endereço de memória *reinterpretado* como outra coisa (a estrutura ou a classe), de forma que o código saiba *remapear* a memória e assim a encontrar o endereço dos componentes do elemento ou classe a partir do ponteiro original.

Uma outra razão para usar uma tradução literal é permitir que a pessoa *consiga* encontrar o termo depois, em literaturas mais avançadas -- onde o termo simplesmente não é traduzido -- ou mesmo na literatura original.

Comment: Sim, parecem-me bons conselhos, sendo um termo tão vulgar nos textos em inglês julguei que por esta altura já existiria uma lexia ou forma canónica de usar a expressão.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia!
Acredito que o termo mais adequado neste caso seja realmente desreferenciar. Caso isso soe estranho, tente colocar uma breve explicação junto do que esse comando realmente faz. Penso que ao menos quem for ler o código vai entender, e se não entender, uma breve consulta já resolve.

Comment: Pois, em inglês soa melhor de facto, nota que inclusivamente, o corretor identifica a palavra como um erro ortográfico, mas enfim, é o que temos.