# Qual a diferença entre * e ** em linguagem C

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados

Se eu tenho uma função `XPTO(int *v1 , int *m1 )` onde `V1` é um vetor e `m1` uma matriz, qual a diferença substancial entre eles na função?

A exemplo:

```
void ElementoVetorEMatriz ( int n, int m, float *vetor, float **matriz) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
      for(int j=0 ; j<m ; j++) {
        int valorAtualMatriz = matriz[i][j];

        for(int k=0 ; k<n ;k++) {
          int valorAtualVetor = vetor[k]; 
          if(valorAtualMatriz == valorAtualVetor) {
            printf("linha %i e coluna %i\n", i , j);
          }
        }
        
      }
    }
}

int main(void) {
  int N=3;
  int M=4;
  
  float vetor1[] = {1.0,7.0,11.0};
  
  float vetor2[3][4] = {
    1.0 , 1.0 , 3.0 , 4.0 ,
    5.0 , 6.0 , 7.0 , 8.0 ,
    9.0 , 10.0 ,11.0, 2.0
  };

  ElementoVetorEMatriz(N , M ,vetor1 , vetor2);

}
```

Encontro um erro no `vetor2` por que ele dá erro de `segmentation fault`.

Por via das dúvidas, esse é o objetivo da função: Dado um vetor de n números reais e uma matriz nxm de números reais, informe qual a linha e coluna de cada elemento da matriz que seja igual a um dos elementos do vetor.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse contexto, em C, `*` é o operador de *dereference* (veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/513135/76558) para informações sobre a tradução do termo, se tiver interesse). Esta operação é caracterizada por acessar o valor presente no endereço de memória que está armazenado na variável.

Em seu exemplo você define uma "lista multidimensional" `vetor2[3][4]`. O modelo dessa variável na memória será de 12 inteiros sequenciais. Porém o **tipo** da variável `vetor2` é `int [3][4]`. É definida como uma lista de inteiros de 2 dimensões. Por esse motivo você não obtém o resultado esperado ao tentar acessar o terceiro elemento da lista como `vetor[2]`. É necessário usar a notação `vetor[0][2]`.

[Esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/are-arrays-pointers) tem boas respostas no que diz respeito à diferença entre ponteiros e listas, de forma geral. Boa parte da confusão vem do fato de o compilador gerenciar bem a conversão implícita entre listas unidimensionais e ponteiros para um tipo. Podemos usar `int *` e `int []` como se fossem a mesma coisa.

Vamos focar agora em seu código. Possíveis soluções para o seu problema seriam:

1. Mudar o tipo da variável `matriz` em `ElementoVetorEMatriz`. As opções possíveis seriam:
   1.1. `float (*matriz)[4]`
   1.2. `float matriz[][4]` (`matriz[]` é interpretado como um ponteiro pelo compilador neste caso)
   1.3. `float matriz[][m]` (**Válido a partir de C99**. Você pode aproveitar o fato de que `m` é um argumento da função - importante frisar que ele deve vir **antes** de `matriz`, como é o caso - para podermos trabalhar de forma mais dinâmica)
   1.4. `float matriz[n][m]` (mesma lógica acima)
   1.5. `float matriz[3][4]`
2. Usando alocação dinâmica de memória, definir um ponteiro para ponteiro para `int` na função `main` e reservar espaço para três ponteiros para `float` nele. Algo como:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

// ...
  float vetor2[3][4] = {
    1.0 , 1.0 , 3.0 , 4.0 ,
    5.0 , 6.0 , 7.0 , 8.0 ,
    9.0 , 10.0 ,11.0, 2.0
  };

  // Reservamos memória para armazenar 3 ponteiros para float
  float **vetor3 = (float **)malloc(N * sizeof(float *));
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    vetor3[i] = vetor2[i]; // Apontamos cada linha de vetor3 para a equivalente em vetor2
  }

  ElementoVetorEMatriz(N , M ,vetor1 , vetor3); // Usamos `vetor3` ao invés de `vetor2`

  free(vetor3); // Liberamos a memória reservada
```

A melhor solução depende da sua aplicação específica.

### Adendo

Não faz parte da sua pergunta, mas note que na função `ElementoVetorEMatriz` você está usando variáveis do tipo `int` para receber valores de `matriz`, que são `float`. Está acontecendo uma [conversão implícita de tipos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) (**leitura em inglês**) que pode causar perda de precisão.

### Leitura complementar sobre ponteiros em C

Em C, ponteiros são variáveis que armazenam um endereço de memória.

[image: Modelo de memória com uso de ponteiros] [Fonte](http://wiki.foz.ifpr.edu.br/wiki/index.php/Ponteiros_em_C)

No exemplo acima, `lp` é um ponteiro para inteiro. Na quarta linha, usa-se o operador `&` para armazenar em `lp` o endereço de memória referente à variável `x`.

Respondendo à pergunta, a diferença entre `*` e `**`, no contexto de ponteiros, é que o primeiro representa uma única derreferência, enquanto o segundo representa duas. Um exemplo prático:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char x = 'A';
  char *str = "String";
  char *p;
  char **pp;

  // #1
  printf("%s @ %p\n", str, &str);
  pp = &str;
  printf("%p %p %p %p %p\n\n", str, &str, *pp, pp, &pp);

  // #2
  p = &x;
  pp = &p;
  printf("%c %c %c\n", x, *p, **pp);
  printf("%p %p %p %p %p\n", &x, p, *pp, pp, &pp);
}
```

Com os 2 exemplos acima buscamos exemplificar um pouco melhor o uso de ponteiros.

##### Exemplo 1

```c
  printf("%s @ %p\n", str, &str);
  pp = &str;
  printf("%p %p %p %p %p\n\n", str, &str, *pp, pp, &pp);
```

Inicialmente mostramos na tela a string armazenada no endereço de memória para onde `str` aponta e o endereço na memória onde a própria variável `str` está armazenada.

Em seguida, armazenamos na variável `pp` o endereço de memória da variável `str` e exibimos:

1. o endereço de memória para o qual a variável `str` aponta
2. o endereço de memória onde a variável `str` está armazenada
3. o valor que está presente no endereço de memória para onde `pp` aponta
4. o endereço de memória para onde a variável `pp` aponta
5. o endereço de memória onde a variável `pp` está armazenada

Segue o resultado desse bloco de código na minha máquina (caso você execute em sua máquina, **muito provavelmente** obterá valores diferentes):

```
String @ 0x7ffc9c7b5aa0
0x559e6c84f004 0x7ffc9c7b5aa0 0x559e6c84f004 0x7ffc9c7b5aa0 0x7ffc9c7b5ab0
```

Conseguimos identificar que:

- `str` e `*pp` apontam para o mesmo endereço de memória (o endereço na *stack* onde a string estática `"String"` foi definida quando o código foi compilado)
- `&str` e `pp` possuem o mesmo valor. Isso é resultado da segunda linha do bloco, onde fizemos `pp` apontar para o endereço de memória de `str`
- o valor de `pp` está armazenado em um endereço de memória totalmente diferente dos demais

Na memória, esses dados estão armazenados como segue:

[image: Modelo de memória para o primeiro exemplo]

##### Exemplo 2

```c
  p = &x;
  pp = &p;
  printf("%c %c %c\n", x, *p, **pp);
  printf("%p %p %p %p %p\n", &x, p, *pp, pp, &pp);
```

Desta vez armazenamos em `p` o endereço da variável `x` e em `pp` o endereço de `p`. O resultado dos `printf`s é como segue:

```
A A A
0x7ffc9c7b5a9f 0x7ffc9c7b5a9f 0x7ffc9c7b5a9f 0x7ffc9c7b5aa8 0x7ffc9c7b5ab0
```

Para acessar o valor de `x` a partir `pp` precisamos derreferenciá-lo duas vezes. A primeira derreferência nos dá o endereço de `x` e a segunda o valor armazenado naquele endereço de memória.

A memória, nesse caso, estaria mais ou menos como segue:

[image: Modelo de memória para o segundo exemplo]

Há muito mais o que se discutir sobre ponteiros em C. Recomendo os seguintes livros para quem tiver interesse em se aprofundar no assunto e na linguagem como um todo:

- [C. A Linguagem de Programação Padrão ANSI](https://www.amazon.com.br/C-Linguagem-Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Padr%C3%A3o-ANSI/dp/8570015860)
- [*Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets*](https://www.amazon.com.br/Expert-Programming-Peter-Van-Linden/dp/0131774298) (infelizmente não possui versão em português)

Comment: A formatação e organização está bem completa, nesses casos quase compensa em vez de postar como resposta fazer um post separado (com uma pergunta canônica de referência para muitas pessoas) e fechar essa como duplicata. Ficou um baita artigo legal num post muito específico (e já com alguns votos para fechar) - caso ocorra o fechamento, considere a possibilidade de fazer um par "pergunta resposta" e mover a solução para lá (sempre vendo se o assunto ainda não foi discutido em outra postagem, claro).

Answer (score 0):

Um asterisco é um ponteiro, e um duplo asterisco é um ponteiro para ponteiro.

No caso `**matriz` provavelmente espera receber um array de duas dimensões.

Adicionalmente, seu `vetor2` está declarado como uma matriz de duas dimensões, mas inicializado como uma matriz de uma dimensão. Tente adicionar chaves extras para agrupar os dados pertencentes às linhas.

Comment: Tentei usar 

`float vetor2[3][4] = {
    {1.0 , 1.0 , 3.0 , 4.0} ,
    {5.0 , 6.0 , 7.0 , 8.0} ,
    {9.0 , 10.0 ,11.0, 2.0}
  };`

Mas mesmo assim ele continua dando erro

Comment: É o mesmo erro, ou ele mudou?

Comment: Mesmo erro 
´´´
signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)
´´´