# Como a especificação da linguagem C utiliza "endereço" na sua definição de ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória

Fiz a pergunta [Quão abstratos são ponteiros em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/507427/357) e uma parte do que eu queria saber era isso que estou perguntando aqui.

C define o tipo de dado ponteiro como sendo uma varíável cujo valor é o "endereço" (*address*) de uma outra variável, cujo tipo é definido na declaração.

C deixa propositalmente em aberto a definição de "endereço", para permitir maior liberdade às diferentes implementações da linguagem, embora esse "endereço" em geral signifique a posição na memória onde fica o valor dessa variável.

Para aumentar a confusão, [li aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1354409/2241463) que C define que um ponteiro pode sempre ser convertido (*cast*) para um inteiro e esse inteiro convertido de volta para um ponteiro, porém esse mapeamento fica a cargo da implementação. Esse tipo de coisa realmente causa confusão ao fazer parecer que um ponteiro não guarda nada além de um inteiro que é uma posição qualquer na memória.

O que eu gostaria de ver respondido aqui é a confirmação se é assim mesmo, com um pouco mais de esclarecimentos, correções de alguma eventual inconsistência no que tiver perguntado, e quais seriam algumas possíveis alternativas a definir "endereço" como posição na memória.

Pode ser uma só mas bem ilustrativa; por exemplo, eu li em [comentário do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151377/what-exactly-is-a-c-pointer-if-not-a-memory-address#comment21337793_15151542) que se você deseja emular uma máquina com endereçamento de, por exemplo, 32 bits, sobre uma máquina física de 16 bits (portanto com menos memória), você pode mapear a memória para um disco rígido e os "endereços" passam a ser as posições de cada dado em disco, deixando portanto de ser endereços de memória.

Comment: Desconheço que variável possa ter referência e valor, ou tem um ou outro, mesmo em Python. O que está em disco é memória.

Comment: Bem observado, fiz confusão ao ler o material. _"Todas as variáveis no Python têm um valor (a porção de dados à qual elas se referem) e uma referência (o local na memória dessa porção de dados). Atribuições em Python copiam apenas a referência"_. Achei que a variável era alguma estrutura que "continha" as duas coisas.

Comment: _"O que está em disco é memória"_ ok, minha definição estava um pouco restrita. Se persiste no tempo é memória, _noted_. Não tenho conhecimento suficiente para saber se o sistema operacional tem  endereçamento único para todas a memória encontrada no computador. Não havendo mais observações, devo considerar que as premissas da pergunta estão basicamente corretas.

Comment: A especificações C posteriores a C89 não determinam como serão realizadas a conversão dos endereços lógicos(espaço de endereçamento do usuário) para endereços memória física pois essa tarefa fica a cargo da [ABI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187944/137387) para a qual o código foi compilado.

Answer (score -1):

Eu não sou um estudioso da linguagem C, portanto não me atrevo a falar sobre sua *especificação*. No entanto, posso fornecer um exemplo específico que talvez ajude a compreender melhor.

Atualmente, os sistemas operacionais de PCs possuem gerenciadores de memória, ofuscação de ponteiros e operam em processadores de 64 bits, o que significa que o contexto de programação C que temos hoje, especialmente em ambientes acadêmicos, difere bastante dos anos 1970, quando C foi especificado. No entanto, a programação de sistemas embarcados se assemelha mais ao ambiente daquela época.

Vamos tomar como exemplo o microcontrolador nRF52840. A especificação de seus pinos de entrada e saída, chamados em inglês de *GPIO - General Purpose Input/Output*, pode ser encontrada [nesta página](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fps_nrf52840%2Fgpio.html).

Nela, é mencionado que o endereço base dos registradores de GPIO é `0x50000000` e que os registradores responsáveis pelo valor de saída do pino possuem um *offset* (deslocamento) de `0x504` posições de memória. Embora não esteja explicitamente indicado, é implícito que o tamanho do registrador é de 32 bits.

Assim, um código para programar o pino 0 do microcontrolador pode se parecer com isso:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#define GPIO_BASE_ADDRESS 0x50000000
#define GPIO_OUT_OFFSET   0x504

void main() {
    // TODO: inicializar corretamente o microcontrolador

    uint32_t *gpio_out_reg = (uint32_t *)(GPIO_BASE_ADDRESS + GPIO_OUT_OFFSET);

    *gpio_out_reg = 1;

    // Trava o código, pois programas de sistemas embarcados geralmente não retornam
    while(1);
}
```

O código está criando um ponteiro para uma posição absoluta da memória e, ao escrever nesse ponteiro, ele está escrevendo na posição de memória.

**Importante:** Eu não testei esse código e ele provavelmente não funcionará exatamente como está, já que é necessário inicializar vários registradores do microcontrolador para que ele opere de maneira adequada.

Uma dúvida que pode surgir é com relação ao que é o tipo `uint32_t`. Eu uso esse tipo porque a especificação da linguagem C é vaga ao definir o que é um `int`. Alguns compiladores tratam `int` como tendo 16 bits, outros como 32 bits, e ainda há aqueles que consideram 64 bits. Sem o tipo `uint32_t`, eu teria que estudar o manual do compilador e descobrir qual tipo usar. Usando `uint32_t`, eu especifico para o compilador que quero que a variável tenha 32 bits sem sinal. Para usar esse tipo, é necessário incluir `#include <stdint.h>`.

Você expressou na sua pergunta a dúvida sobre a conversão de int para ponteiro. No código acima, essa conversão está implícita, mas podemos torná-la mais explícita no exemplo abaixo:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#define GPIO_BASE_ADDRESS 0x50000000
#define GPIO_OUT_OFFSET   0x504

void main() {
    // TODO: inicializar corretamente o microcontrolador

    uint32_t gpio_base_address = 0x50000000;
    uint32_t *gpio_out_reg = (uint32_t *)(gpio_base_address + 0x504);

    *gpio_out_reg = 1;

    // Trava o código, pois programas de sistemas embarcados geralmente não retornam
    while(1);
}
```

Perceba que códigos como esse, que acessam diretamente posições de memória cria sérios riscos de segurança em sistemas operacionais multitarefa. Por isso, processadores de PC possuem um componente chamado MMU (*Memory Management Unit* - Unidade de Gerenciamento de Memória) que detecta e bloqueia acessos indevidos à memória, emitindo alertas para o sistema operacional. Por isso, códigos desse tipo geram o erro *Segmentation Fault* ao serem executados em PCs.

Para finalizar, apresentei um exemplo de conversão de `int` (ou melhor `uint32_t`) para ponteiro. Mas por que precisamos converter ponteiros para inteiros? Um caso possível é durante o debug do código: ao depurar o código, é possível solicitar ao debugger que apresente o endereço de memória de interesse (e para apresentar o valor, é necessário converter o ponteiro em um inteiro). Com essa informação em mãos, é possível inspecionar o conteúdo da memória.

***Edit:*** você fez a pergunta se um ponteiro é apenas um inteiro que é uma posição qualquer na memória. Eu dei um exemplo em que isso é verdade, mas essa não é a resposta completa. A resposta real para essa pergunta é: "depende do compilador".

Como você mesmo já viu, a especificação deixa em aberto como os ponteiros são implementados. Então, se algum compilador resolver implementar de uma forma completamente diferente, ele pode, conforme o grau de criatividade dos criadores do compilador. Mas por qual motivo um compilador implementaria de uma forma diferente do tradicional se o tradicional é método o mais eficiente? Um motivo já citado para implementar de modo diferente é fazer ofuscação de ponteiros, em que os ponteiros deixam de apontar para memórias reais, com o objetivo de diminuir pontos que estão expostos a hackers. De qualquer forma, se algum dia surgir uma memória revolucionária, cujo acesso não dependa mais de endereços numéricos, não será preciso mudar a especificação da linguagem C, mas apenas a implementação do compilador.

Comment: Não é verdade que depende do compilador, a maneira com a qual os endereços são mapeados dentro do espaço de endereçamento do usuário é determinada pela ABI(Application Binary Interface) para qual o código foi compilado.